# What is the type of an object imported from another database into Spark 2?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm importing two tables from oracle into Spark like this :

```
val customers = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:user/password@//IP:2222/ebe").option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").option("dbtable", "customers").load().show()

val cities = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:user/password@//IP:2222/ebe").option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").option("dbtable", "cities").load().show()
```

These tables should be later joined by "ID" like this:

`val df = customers.join(cities, customers.col("ID") === cities.col("ID"))`

The problem is the types of the objects "customers" and "cities" respectively is `customers: Unit = ()`
`cities: Unit = ()`

There are answers here that explain how to convert from Seq() to DataFrame, but nothing about Unit to DataFrame.

What is this Unit, is it RDD, DataSet or ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you put `show()` at the end. `show()` has type `Unit`, therefore your `customers` and `cities` have type `Unit`.

You should write:

```
val customers = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:user/password@//IP:2222/ebe").option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").option("dbtable", "customers").load()
val cities = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:user/password@//IP:2222/ebe").option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").option("dbtable", "cities").load()
```

Then they should be `DataFrame` or some `Dataset` you can then process further.